# Python- count number of same entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list (that I've also made into a pandas data frame) of entries. Some of the entries are the same.
For example:
names = ['John', 'Joe', 'Teddy', 'Joe', 'Jack', 'Joe', 'John'] 
I want to make a data frame that displays each entry and the corresponding count, such that there would be one column with ['John', 'Joe', 'Teddy', 'Jack'] and another with the corresponding frequencies, [2, 3, 1, 1].

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `names = pd.Series(names); names.groupby(names).count().to_frame('Name')`

Comment: You can also use collections counter to create a dict first.